How do you access page name and URL from within LocalSettings.php in MediaWiki?
I am using a $wgHooks to insert some OpenGraph / meta information in the <HEAD> section of the page on my MediaWiki site.
I can currently add site-wide information such as site name. However, I want to add page-specific information to the <HEAD> section.
How can I access the page's title and URL from within LocalSettings.php, to insert it into the $wgHooks?
I have searched the MediaWiki help pages, and forum sites, but can't find any information about how to access page-specific information from within LocalSettings.php. I understand that LocalSettings.php is intended for site-wide configuration information, but this is the way I'm inserting tags into the <HEAD>. I have read about creating an extension but I am hoping there is an easier way.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It depends on which hook you use. If it is OutputPageParserOutput, the hooked function receives OutputPage $out; the OutputPage class has getContext() method, returning IContextSource, which has getTitle() method, returning Title, which has a few useful methods.
For example:
$wgHooks['OutputPageParserOutput'] = static function ( OutputPage $out, ParserOutput $parserOutput ): bool {
    $title = $out->getContext()->getTitle();
    if ( $title ) {
        $page_title = $title->getText();
        $page_url = $title->->getCanonicalURL();
    }
    // etc.
    return true;
};

If the hook is BeforePageDisplay, the same OutputPage object should be used:
$wgHooks['OutputPageParserOutput'] = static function ( MediaWiki\Output\OutputPage $out, Skin $skin ): bool {
    $title = $out->getContext()->getTitle();
    if ( $title ) {
        $page_title = $title->getText();
        $page_url = $title->->getCanonicalURL();
    }
    // etc.
    return true;
};


Thank you, I am using "BeforePageDisplay":
`function add_html_to_head(&$out, &$skin)
{
$meta="<meta property="og:site_name" content="Site Name">";
$out->addHeadItem('my_html_code', $meta);
}
$wgHooks['BeforePageDisplay'][] = 'add_html_to_head';`

In general, RequestContext::getMain()->getTitle() will work in pretty much any hook. In LocalSettings.php itself (outside hooks), there is no way to access the title as the application state hasn't been inititalized yet.
